# how to filter Excel data, by text length?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2007, I want to filter rows by one of my columns text length, eg. hide the rows with  text lengths less or greater than 12 characters.
what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

you can use an autofilter. select 'custom', choose 'equals', and enter 12 question marks for the criteria.

Answer (score 3):

In another column, create a formula that shows the length of the target column... fill it down, and then filter based on that column.

```
=LEN(A1)
```

Comment: yeah, but how do you filter...